# File.Copy() fails or doesn't execute, program can't use supposed-to-be-copied file

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have a simple program to take a screenshot, save that screenshot to the current folder (where the exe is) then copy that file over into an archiving folder. Here is what I have.

```
public const string ext = "png";
public static int id = new Random().Next(1, 999999999);
public const string archivefolder = "AnonShot Screenshot Archives";
public static string archivepath = info.path + "\\" + info.archivefolder;
public static string filename = "Screenshot-" + info.id.ToString();
public static string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
public static string fullpath = info.archivepath + "\\" + info.filename + "." + info.ext;

...

// Copy the screenshot into the archive folder
string source = info.path + "\\" + info.filename + "." + info.ext;
string destination = info.archivepath;
File.Copy(source, destination + Path.GetFileName(source));
```

(entire file can be found at http://pastebin.com/Fr9yzJcZ)

The saving of the file works (an example being Screenshot-123456789.png) but when it is supposed to copy that file to the archive folder, it errors saying

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Could not find a part of the path '\AnonShot Screenshot Archives\Screenshot-123456789.png'.

That's because the file hasn't been copied over to that folder yet, because the `File.Copy` command isn't doing it's job, so I believe.

Comment: Do you have Write permissions allowed on the folder you're trying to upload the files to?

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan Yep, even launched as administrator and same result.

Comment: Does the folder actually exist already? Also, as an aside, picking a random number between 1 and 999999999 is a terrible naming scheme.

Comment: @MattBurland Yep, folder exists. The reason it's a random number between 1 and 999,999,999 is because it's suppose to be a random URL pushed to a file server that doesn't use accounts, if you have any better naming ideas tell me :P

Comment: Wheres the code where you originally write the file? Your File.Copy is complaining there is no image, so very likely the problem is in creating that image. I would also recommend against using Random() to generate unique ID's, you probably want to use a GUID instead.

Comment: Use a timestamp plus a user id. Use a GUID. Use an incrementing counter. Is there an inner exception? [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is fairly unambiguous. Does the file (in the destination folder) already exist?

Comment: @UnicornoMarley AnonScreenshot.exe runs, you click the button, it captures and saves the picture to the same folder, then it complains about the can't find part of path error. The exe and file "Screenshot-123456789.png" are in the same folder. As for the GUID thing, a example would be appreciated if you answer.

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure without a better-formed code example. But I strongly suspect you need to call Directory.Create(destination) before trying to copy the file. Also, use Path.Combine() to combine filename parts, not string concatenation.

Comment: We can't examine the variables, or see what's in the directory structure on your system. Use the debugger, step through the code, see what exactly is assigned to the variables, and then see how it matches your system's existing directories.

Comment: @MattBurland I was originally using a timestamp on it though ditched it, likely will start using it again. An incrementing counter would be a bit more complex than I know of PHP, which is what the program posts to for uploading the file to the server. The destination folder doesn't have the file in it at all, no.

Comment: @Scarsz http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx theyre basically globally unique ID's, you'd statistically have to generate them for billions of years before getting a duplicate.

Comment: @KenWhite MattBurland PeterDuniho I've added a pastebin link to the entire file.

Comment: Are you sure the the original file has been written, and doesn't has an exclusive lock on it.

Comment: @Amleth That's what I'm thinking is the problem, though I don't really know any way of checking if it's possible to copy it or it isn't already being used by something. (Sorry, first program/time programming anything really in C#)

Comment: Try using explorer to copy the file, if explorer cannot copy it, it would be unlikely they your application can copy it. It could also be a permissions issue, does you application run in the context of a user, or is it a Web Application or service.

Comment: @Amleth Explorer copies it fine, and there isn't any permission issues. Everything's handled in a simple exe that opens and you click a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was as the best I am aware caused by the program trying to find literally "\Anon..." instead of "C:\Users..."

Having the code get the current directory through `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` fixed the problem for me.